# Rails 3.1 SQL sum only negative numbers

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I've got this code I'm using to insert data into Highcharts

```
def self.amount_on(date)
      where("date(created_at) = ?",date).sum(:amount)
end
```

I would like to only `sum` an `:amount` if it's negative.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def self.amount_on(date)
  where("amount > 0 AND date(created_at) = ?",date).sum(:amount)
end
```

Comment: What if I also wanted to include results from a table called `order` where the `orderstatus_id = 5`?

Comment: @bcackerman you just gonna need to use joins.. check out the complete reference http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @Bassam Mechanni, thanks for your answer
in the where condition amount should be less than zero as per the question 
 where("amount < 0 AND date(created_at) = ?",date).sum(:amount)